# jodconverter loadLibrary message

Tags: jodconverter

jodConverter 4.2.2
Windows 10
amazon corretto 8 for the java jdk, 1.8.0_212
running from IntelliJ Community (latest)
LibreOffice 6.1.3.1 (64 bit) - installed and runs fine

I try to run this bit of simple code (please excuse bad formatting):

```
import org.jodconverter.office.OfficeManager;
import org.jodconverter.office.LocalOfficeManager;
import org.jodconverter.JodConverter;
import org.jodconverter.office.OfficeUtils;

import java.io.File;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        OfficeManager officeManager = LocalOfficeManager.builder()
                .install()
                .officeHome("C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice")
                .build();
        File inputFile = new File("c:\\users\\dlawler\\desktop\\test.rtf");
        File outputFile = new File("c:\\users\\dlawler\\desktop\\test.pdf");
        try {
            // Start an office process and connect to the started instance (on port 2002).
            officeManager.start();
            // Convert
            JodConverter
                    .convert(inputFile)
                    .to(outputFile)
                    .execute();
        } catch (OfficeException e) {

        } finally {
            // Stop the office process
            OfficeUtils.stopQuietly(officeManager);
        }
    }
}
```

And I get an error that pops up on the screen:

LoadLibrary failed with error 87: The parameter is incorrect

This is the log:

> "C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=51201:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_212\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Projects\Converter\out\production\Converter;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\jodconverter\jodconverter-local\4.2.2\jodconverter-local-4.2.2.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\jodconverter\jodconverter-core\4.2.2\jodconverter-core-4.2.2.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.7\commons-lang3-3.7.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.5\gson-2.8.5.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\openoffice\juh\4.1.2\juh-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\openoffice\jurt\4.1.2\jurt-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\openoffice\ridl\4.1.2\ridl-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\openoffice\unoil\4.1.2\unoil-4.1.2.jar;C:\Users\dlawler.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.6\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.3.6\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\classes\java_uno.jar;C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\classes\juh.jar;C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\classes\jurt.jar" com.connexin.converter.Main
>   2019-07-03 17:21:40 INFO  OfficeProcessManager:294 - Submitting task 'Start' and waiting...
>   2019-07-03 17:21:40 INFO  OfficeDescriptor:97 - soffice info (from exec path): Product: LibreOffice - Version: ??? - useLongOptionNameGnuStyle: true
>   2019-07-03 17:21:40 INFO  OfficeProcess:395 - Starting process with acceptString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager' and profileDir 'C:\Users\dlawler\AppData\Local\Temp.jodconverter_socket_host-127.0.0.1_port-2002_tcpNoDelay-1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:40 DEBUG AbstractProcessManager:140 - Command line matches! Returning pid: 25300
>   2019-07-03 17:21:40 INFO  OfficeProcess:402 - Started process; pid = 25300
>   2019-07-03 17:21:40 DEBUG OfficeConnection:91 - Connecting with connectString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:42 DEBUG OfficeConnection:91 - Connecting with connectString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:43 DEBUG OfficeConnection:91 - Connecting with connectString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:44 DEBUG OfficeConnection:91 - Connecting with connectString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:45 DEBUG OfficeConnection:91 - Connecting with connectString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:47 DEBUG OfficeConnection:91 - Connecting with connectString 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 DEBUG OfficeProcessManager:303 - ExecutionException catched in submitAndWait
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: Office process died with exit code -1073740791
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.submitAndWait(OfficeProcessManager.java:299)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.startAndWait(OfficeProcessManager.java:254)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManagerPoolEntry.doStart(OfficeProcessManagerPoolEntry.java:168)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.start(AbstractOfficeManagerPoolEntry.java:144)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPool.doStart(AbstractOfficeManagerPool.java:188)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.AbstractOfficeManagerPool.start(AbstractOfficeManagerPool.java:113)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.LocalOfficeManager.start(LocalOfficeManager.java:38)
>       at com.connexin.converter.Main.main(Main.java:23)
>   Caused by: org.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: Office process died with exit code -1073740791
>       at org.jodconverter.office.ConnectRetryable.attempt(ConnectRetryable.java:87)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.AbstractRetryable.execute(AbstractRetryable.java:57)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.ConnectRetryable.execute(ConnectRetryable.java:26)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.doStartProcessAndConnect(OfficeProcessManager.java:104)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.access$100(OfficeProcessManager.java:40)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager$4.call(OfficeProcessManager.java:261)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager$4.call(OfficeProcessManager.java:256)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: org.jodconverter.office.OfficeConnectionException: Connection failed: 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'; java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeConnection.connect(OfficeConnection.java:170)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.ConnectRetryable.attempt(ConnectRetryable.java:61)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: com.sun.star.connection.NoConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at com.sun.star.lib.connections.socket.socketConnector.connect(socketConnector.java:144)
>       at com.sun.star.comp.connections.Connector.connect(Connector.java:119)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeConnection.connect(OfficeConnection.java:106)
>       ... 11 more
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 INFO  AbstractOfficeManagerPool:195 - Stopping the office manager pool...
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 INFO  OfficeProcessManager:294 - Submitting task 'Stop' and waiting...
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 DEBUG OfficeProcessManager:138 - Exception catched in doStopProcess
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.doStopProcess(OfficeProcessManager.java:124)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager.access$000(OfficeProcessManager.java:40)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager$5.call(OfficeProcessManager.java:283)
>       at org.jodconverter.office.OfficeProcessManager$5.call(OfficeProcessManager.java:278)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 INFO  OfficeProcess:206 - Trying to forcibly terminate process: 'host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'; pid: 25300
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 INFO  OfficeProcessManager:158 - process forcibly terminated with code -1073740791
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 INFO  OfficeProcessManager:77 - process exited with code -1073740791
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 DEBUG OfficeProcess:123 - Deleting instance profile directory 'C:\Users\dlawler\AppData\Local\Temp.jodconverter_socket_host-127.0.0.1_port-2002_tcpNoDelay-1'
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 DEBUG OfficeProcessManager:300 - Task 'Stop' executed successfully
>   2019-07-03 17:21:48 INFO  AbstractOfficeManagerPool:213 - Office manager stopped

Process finished with exit code 0

Any idea of what to look for would be MOST appreciated.  I'm wondering if Symantec is blocking the ports?  64 bit/32 bit mismatch?

Comment: On a whim I tried to compile and run the tests for jodconverter itself, with the exact same result.  I'm guessing the issue has to do with a mismatch between the LibreOffice version I'm using and the projects own LibreOffice jars?  I'm going to look more into the building process for jodconverter itself...

Answer (score 0):

So this has to be a local configuration/system error.  I set up the same environment on two other PCs (not in our corporate network) and jodconverter compiled and ran it's tests with no issue.  I'm looking into any possible differences (firewall, anti-virus, other loaded programs), that could account for the different behaviors...

Update: this turned out to be the drivers for the super old AMD graphics card in this machine (AMD Radeon HD 7300).  The solution was to go into C:\Windows\System32 and rename atig6pxx.dll to atig6pxx.dll.bak.  I have not experienced any issues after doing this - but I expect this will disable opengl with this card.  For the moment that is not an issue.